# sound alarm from terminal emulator

Tags: notifications, alarm, scripts, bash

For my purposes, I want to create a simple bash script, that will notify me when appropriate conditions will meet. Is there a way to make a sound alert from Android Terminal Emulator? I'm running Cyanogenmod 10.1.

Comment: beep and echo -e "\007" don't work on the S4 anyway. Can you use aplay "something.wav" or similar. There seems to be no default beeper (though I would need someone to verify that).

Comment: @RossC  And how to play a `.wav` file from Android Terminal Emulator?

Comment: Ross didn't write "play a something.wav", but `aplay something.wav` – so I assume `aplay` is the command used for that? `aplay` could stand for "audio player", at least (yuck, but might rather be "[alsa player](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/4.2/hardware/qcom/audio/libalsa-intf/aplay.c)").

Comment: It should work but I can't seem to get it running. aplay should lead audio player. There's a lot of Linux commands not in android sadly.

Comment: see this: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205576/how-to-play-sound-from-termux-when-using-linux