# How to Play Sound from Termux when using Linux?

Tags: audio, linux, termux, vnc

I have a problem with audio streaming that I can not listen audio from Pulseaudio when using VNC with a Linux Desktop Environment.

However it works if I export the audio to XSDL. But the problem is that after I exit the application the sound does not work in the background.

I know that Pulseaudio only supports Xorg servers, so how to stream audio to VNC or any other application on Android and to run it in the background.

I know that there is an application [Simple Protocol Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kaytat.simpleprotocolplayer) that listens to pulseaudio sound from Xorg Server, but it does not work for me and I do not know the reason.

Comment: Which is your client, Linux or Termux? Which computer are you trying to get the audio to work on, the client or the server? Which device is PulseAudio installed on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possibilities I know of, to play sound from a Linux environment on Android device:

- Play through native ALSA libraries
- Stream through PulseAudio

  - Forward to X Server (on UNIX or TCP socket)
  - Stream over IP (TCP or UDP) e.g. when using VNC

First method works natively through ALSA kernel module/drivers while second and third work through `PulseAudio` libraries i.e. different [modules and protocols](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/) (`pulseaudio` package should be installed on Termux / Linux distro).

Mostly Android OEMs base their sound architecture on ALSA, though [not necessary](https://source.android.com/devices/audio/):

> *"You can use Advanced Linux Sound Architecture (ALSA), Open Sound System (OSS), or a custom driver"*

In case of ALSA kernel lists devices in `/dev/snd/` which can be manipulated to direct sound towards sound card. Complete tutorial can be found [here](https://github.com/meefik/linuxdeploy/issues/223#issuecomment-339116666). It works, but not for all sound formats. It's because ALSA drivers loaded on Android devices can't be controlled (at least I could not) through standard Linux userspace tools in straightforward manner because they aren't compatible (refer to changes/additions in Linux kernel by Google/OEMs, the closed source proprietary HALs in userspace, and differences in [ALSA vs. TinyALSA](http://www.voidcn.com/article/p-vbcwmalz-bht.html)). Also access to `/proc/asound/` is not possible without root, see details in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217522/218526). ALSA project is [here](https://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc).

Also there are more customized solutions that work with ALSA and PulseAudio both such as [Music Player Daemon](https://www.musicpd.org/).

**When using X Server:**
`XSDL Server` is the only well developed X server Android app I know of, no more developed unfortunately. It has a built-in PulseAudio server with `module-cli-protocol-tcp` already loaded, listening on standard port `4712` by default. Once the X Session is started on Linux, we can direct sound from Linux PulseAudio client libraries to XDSL PulseAudio server by setting the following environment variable on Linux:

```
$ export PULSE_SERVER=tcp:127.0.0.1:4712
```

<sup>* 127.0.0.1 indicates that Linux and XDSL are running on same device</sup>

Or to set permanently, edit file:

```
# /etc/pulse/client.conf or ~/.config/pulse/client.conf

default-server = tcp:127.0.0.1:4712
```

Now any media player running in this environment that makes use of PulseAudio client libraries, will stream its audio to XDSL app. You can forward X session display and sound to X server running on a PC as well but that needs a more complicated setup.

**When using VNC:**
VNC protocol by default doesn't support sound. However, PulseAudio server can stream over TCP/UDP using different protocols. There are apps available for Android that can play [`simple protocol`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index20h3) (e.g. *Simple Protocol Player*) and [`real-time transport protocol`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index38h3) (e.g. *VLC*). For this we need to load the related PulseAudio module.
To setup local PulseAudio daemon, first of all comment out following lines:

```
# /etc/pulse/default.pa

#ifexists module-console-kit.so
#load-module module-console-kit
#.endif
```

Otherwise daemon will fail to start if `/usr/lib/pulse*/modules/module-console-kit.so` exists but `consolekit` package isn't installed (which is deprecated, replaced by `systemd-login` and no more present on many Linux repos).

Ensure that `autospawn` is set to `yes` so that we don't need to start daemon manually and it is auto started by Desktop Environment. Not necessary if we start daemon manually.

```
# /etc/pulse/client.conf

# Autospawn a PulseAudio server/daemon when needed
autospawn = yes
```

Now start pulseaudio daemon and note the value of source, for me it's `auto_null.monitor`:

```
$ pulseaudio --start && pactl list | grep -A2 -i RUNNING
$ DISPLAY=:0 pulseaudio --start
```

Load simple-protocol module:

```
$ DISPLAY=:0 pactl load-module module-simple-protocol-tcp rate=48000 format=s16le channels=2 source=auto_null.monitor record=true port=8000 listen=127.0.0.1
```

Or to set permanently, edit file:

```
$ echo 'load-module module-simple-protocol-tcp rate=48000 format=s16le channels=2 source=auto_null.monitor record=true port=8000 listen=127.0.0.1' >> /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Following should be enabled in DE startup settings, necessary because some programs such as `emixer` on `Enlightenment` Desktop Environment works only if PulseAudio server in local X server is published:

```
$ DISPLAY=:0 start-pulseaudio-x11
```

Start Simple Player app and match `bitrate` and `port` set in above command i.e. `48000` and `8000` in my case. Don't use `listen=127.0.0.1` if you want to listen on PC too.

I have tested both of PulseAudio based solutions on `ArchLinuxARM` and `Ubuntu`, and they work without root access. However `SELinux` may restrict access to certain resources if running in non-root context. Also, in order to get network access and create sockets, you have to be member of [inet (3003)](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/system/core/include/cutils/android_filesystem_config.h#147) group necessarily. All apps with [android.permission.INTERNET](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/data/etc/platform.xml#55) granted are member of this group.

Comment: Do you also work on Userland ? ...       Or just on Termux

Comment: @Maher_2000 I tested LinuxDeploy and a few other apps but not UserLAnd. I have developed a Linux environment myself in chroot and namespaces, and I use through ssh and Termux.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried several times to play the sound on a simple protocol player but the sound does not work and the application shows me the message "unable to stream" and also made a mistake in pulseaudio I do not know what the reason and I tried on Termux and Useland but anyway thank you for helping me , Note : I'm new to using Linux and I use the languages translator to speak with you in English so you will notice that my English is not good or understandable for you

Comment: @Maher_2000 are you sure you entered IP, port, bitrate correctly in Simple Protocol Player? If so, the problem is with your Linux configuration. Execute all commands and edit files with great care. Sometimes bad permissions set on files may cause such problems. Since you are not running as root, there is possibility that that you lack permissions for certain tasks. SELinux can be a reason, set it permissive if you can, or view avc denials.

Comment: Yes I enter it correctly as below (127.0.0.1) but do not work with me and show me errors in some commands when executed like the command pctl list which tells me to reject the permission request and it works if you enter the Termux directly and not on the distribution installed on Termux but The problem here is that there is no start-pulseaudio-x11 with the pulseaudio package for Termux and it does not work. Are there other ways to run over TCP if it is receiving streaming audio from the browser directly or other applications?

Comment: Or these two methods only Note when playing pulseaudio On xsdl the sound works well but in the browser it is intermittent and also the sound does not work except on the computer root

Comment: @Maher_2000 it's not `ptcl`, it's `pactl list`. And if it doesn't work, you won't be able to get source of audio stream and it won't work for you definitely. I haven't tried this all in `proot`, so I'm afraid I won't be able to help you. You'll have to trace the causes of `permission denied`.

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake writing the order here because I write quickly and I agree with you that the proot has few powers , Anyway, thank you for helping me

Comment: Just to point out, the `pactl list` works on Termix directly without rooting, but the `start-pulseaudio-x11` command does not work on it

Comment: @Maher_2000 yes because there is no X11 server running on Android in which PulseAudio is published: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index31h3 And also if you want to run media from Linux environment, PulseAudio should also be run from Linux. Media player running on Linux and PulseAudio running on Android won't work.

Comment: I've got the ISSUE discussed on the GITHUB platform on this subject https://github.com/CypherpunkArmory/UserLAnd/issues/135

Comment: There is `play-audio`, please [see](https://github.com/termux/play-audio)

Comment: @user3123159 `play-audio` is a Termux package, so it addresses the first half of the question: ***How to Play Sound from Termux...***, not the second half: ***... when using Linux?***. ALSA and PA in a Linux environment give low level control to audio framework, though one may opt to use high level library like **OpenSL ES** (which `play-audio` uses).

Comment: The question title seems high level - `how-to-play-sound-from-termux-when-using-linux` but the question itself seems low level;) So my comment with `play-audio` is high level as you correctly state - it might be worth a separate answer?

Comment: @user3123159 actually the question is: ***How to Play Sound from commandline when using Linux on Android device?***. So anything specific to Termux is not a solution. But you can add the answer if you want to, with some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Good news, I've been able to extract audio to Simple Protocol Player using the pulseaudio for Android on Termex but the problem is that this method does not work on the offical pulseaudio because it does not have access privileges for have root only if you have root on your system can you extract audio of Simple Protocol player

**WARNING: If the audio does not work, check the link below because there are some notes I did not mention**

## on Termux

---

**Do this command :**

`pactl list sources short`

- *Visit the link below to find out the usefulness of this command before you complete reading*

**And :**

---

Download application

- [Simple Protocol Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kaytat.simpleprotocolplayer)

**And :**

---

```
echo -e "\n# Simple Protocol Player\n\nload-module module-simple-protocol-tcp source=OpenSL_ES_sink.monitor record=true port=12345 rate=44100" >> $PREFIX/etc/pulse/default.pa
```

**And Restart Termux :**

---

close all windows in termux

**And :**

---

`pulseaudio -k`

`pulseaudio --start`

**or only :**

---

`pulseaudio --start`

**now install sox :**

---

`apt install sox`

**And Play sound :**

---

`play [file.mp3]`

For more information visit 
[Link](https://kaytat.com/blog/?page_id=301)

Comment: @IrfanLatif It is not worth placing as a best answer because this method works on Termux only, which can not be used even from within the Linux environment installed on Termux. This is due to the Termux developers who have customized the Pulseaudio package that works well on their app only but cannot works on others applications example Userland or will working if them have access to permission Root

Answer (score 1):

`mpg123 myFile.mp3` (`pkg install mpg123`) will play an mp3 in Termux. To pause, press `ctrl+z`. To resume type `%` and press enter. Press `ctrl+c` while playing to quit.

In addition to the `play` command, which you've mentioned, there's also `play-audio` (`pkg install play-audio`).