# Is it possible to run an X Server and a window manager in TermUX

Tags: linux, termux

I am running the TermUX application on an Android 10 smartphone, and can type in it with my Logitech K480 keyboard. I want to run a window manager like fvwm (see fvwm.org).

I have found an article on the internet which seems to mention i can run VNC server and client or XSDL although the latter is unstable, but as far as I understand I can only do this if i have a separate computer running the server, and then my Android smartphone can run the client window manager from TermUX after changing the DISPLAY environment variable

Is this correct?

How can I run an X Server in TermUX and then simply run the window manager with the startx command like in Linux?

Thanks.

Comment: Termux is a terminal emulator. Original implementation of X Server runs on a Virtual Terminal (kernel console). Is your kernel built with VTs and Framebuffer Console (physical display) support? Most probably no. So you need an Android specific X Server (like the almost abandoned XServer XSDL app) or need to run the original X Server in headless mode which directs its output to a virtual display like VNC. You can then run a VNC client app on localhost (the Android device itself) or some other host on the network (like a PC) to receive the display and interact with the GUI environment.

Comment: Btw X Server programs are built for PCs. Most of them aren't very usable even on a 10-inch tablet screen. So X server running on a phone isn't of much practical use. That's what my experience is. I run Linux distros on Android devices but only with CLI controls.

Comment: Related links: [Is it possible to install Linux on Android device?](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/info-is-it-possible-to-install-windows-ios-or-linux-on-android-device.3763961) and [How to quickly understand the Android UI?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221825/218526) and [How to boot Ubuntu on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220678/218526) and [How to Play Sound from Termux when using Linux?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205629/218526)

Comment: Termux officially supports the two methods I mentioned above to run X Server: https://github.com/termux/x11-packages#using-x11-on-termux. But if your device is rooted and want to try your luck with the existing framebuffer support, start from here: https://github.com/meefik/linuxdeploy/search?o=asc&q=framebuffer&s=created&type=issues. However FB isn't very likely to work with the standard Linux tools because its functionality is very limited or non-standard in many cases and Android relies on closed-source HALs provided by OEMs for most of its interaction with hardware components.

Comment: Afaik what OP is asking for is not possible, however the hacky solution @Irfan Latif mentioned is, and is also given in the termux wiki(https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Graphical_Environment)

Answer (score 1):

You can run either an x-server or a vnc-client on the same Android device you have installed termux on. You don't have to use another device for that.

Instructions are available here https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Graphical_Environment

I suggest you use VNC instead of an x-server.